# Are there any proof assistants that can not be derived from substitution?

Tags: implementation, substitution

Are there any type of proof systems that can **not** be implemented with [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)) at the core?

In essence if I want to implement a base library for building up various proof assistants do I only need substitution or need something else/more?

---

Follow up on comment from Jason Rute

> When you say “implement” a proof assistant, it is unclear how much you are talking about the underlying logical kernel or all the features.

I really only care that the kernel can do what is needed to do proofs. It does not even have to track the steps as that can be handled by the caller. As for the interactive parts with a user for now it does not matter. In other words if I were to implement a core I know with just a single library for substitution and a single file with a few predicates or functions or methods all of the substitution needed can be done. This would include such things as when α-conversion is needed which I can do currently using combination of substitutions in the substitution or as many would expect as a pre-step to substitution.

The other point I need more clarification before I can update the follow up.

---

In implementing various types of proof assistants they typically can be implemented in some form of type system, term rewriting or reduction strategies which can be implemented using substitution. Note speed is not a consideration so even though substitution is slow it works.

I am familiar with implementing such cores for type systems and logic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134112/discussion-on-question-by-guy-coder-are-there-any-proof-assistants-that-can-not).